# SQL find "traps" based on customer, but also find traps based on the customers children

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that currently inner joins Trap table with Customer table, lastly it contains a where statement to only select the ones where Customer.GeoCode is some value.

Now the thing is, some customers can be customers of a customer. Relationally connected through:

Table CustomerToLevel1
Level1ID int - Being the parent customer
CustomerID int - Being the child customer

I want the children of the main customer and their traps to be included through the query, just like the traps of the "main" customer, but unsure about how to approach it.

The code looks as such atm:

```
SELECT Customer.CompanyName, Customer.Address_1 as CompanyAddress, Customer.ZipCode, Customer.City, Customer.CountryCode, Trap.TrapID, Trap.Name
from Trap INNER JOIN Customer On Trap.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID 
WHERE (Customer.CustomerGeoCode='code')
```

Ive tried something like:

```
SELECT Customer.CompanyName, Customer.Address_1 as CompanyAddress, Customer.ZipCode, Customer.City, Customer.CountryCode, Trap.TrapID, Trap.Name
from Trap INNER JOIN Customer On Trap.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID 
WHERE (Customer.CustomerGeoCode='code' OR exists(SELECT NULL from Customer as cs INNER JOIN CustomerToLevel1 ON CustomerToLevel1.Level1ID=Customer.CustomerID AND CustomerToLevel1.CustomerID!=Customer.CustomerID AND CustomerToLevel1.CustomerID=cs.CustomerID ))
```

But that didnt really seem to do the trick, I suspect its another inner join type query I need to do but how exactly to go about it or whether even possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate your question.

Comment: check out recursive CTEs, these are used to collect the parent/child data relationships, then it should be easy to do a join against the Trap. What are you building btw? Some sort of human hunting database, a la Hard Target?